# Replicating features of Doze mode using other tools/apps

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow

target android version: 4.2.2

Doze mode is one of the new features of Android 6.0 Marshmallow; [In the documentation it is said that:](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

The following restrictions apply to your apps while in Doze:

```
Network access is suspended.
The system ignores wake locks.
Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.
The system does not perform Wi-Fi scans.
The system does not allow sync adapters to run.
The system does not allow JobScheduler to run.
```

My question is how we can create Doze mode behavior by tools like Amplify, Greenify or other available tools?

For example how we can create a condition that in which the system ignores wake locks? (What tool/app? what config?)